# How to implement printf style functions in C

Tags: c, printf

How to implement printf style functions in C. I have needed to implement printf style function within a my C code. Otherwise please can anyone give me good examples for function overloading in C. Thanks :)

Comment: C doesn't have function overloading.

Comment: The question is unclear. What does it mean "printf style"? Be more precise in your question. And elaborate on the subject.

Comment: Are you talking about functions which take variable number of arguments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about a variadic function (a.k.a. "varargs function"). If you want a good run-down of how to write one in C, I suggest this link, which specifically talks about printf: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html

Answer (score 4):

You use [variable argument lists](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg) to do this.

An initial argument that somehow contains the information needed to properly decode the type and order of the other arguments is needed, this is the formatting string for `printf()`.